# FindContours of a single channel image in OpenCv (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I've trouble using OpenCV's `findContours(...)` method to find the contours in a single channel image. The image is actually a numpy array with the shape `(128, 128)` and elements with real values between `[0.0,1.0]`. Initially the shape is `(1,128,128,1)` but I've used `np.squeeze(...)` to get rid of the first and last dimension. Keeping either of them doesn't solve my problem.

**What I've tried:**

```
image = np.squeeze(array) #using np.squeeze(array, [0]) won't help.
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, 1, 2)
```

The above code causes the following exception:

```
error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor
```

**What I've also tried:**

If I apply `findContours(...)` directly, so without using `cvtColor(...)`, I get a different error:

```
 error: (-210) [Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode != CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only in function cvStartFindContours_Impl
```

Some sources suggest to use a `threshold` to get an binary image which is required by `findContours(...)`[[1]](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)

```
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 1, 255, 0)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

This won't help either and I receive the same exception complaining about the `CV_8UC1` support.

Comment: what is your image? upload the image with the complete code.

Comment: The image is generated by a autoencoder hence, it’s not really helpful to upload the tensorflow code. It’s just an numpy array with real values between [0,1]. The shape is given in the question.

Comment: "with real values between [0,1]" -- that's the problem -- findContours wants 8bit unsigned integers, not floats or doubles. Scale the values to range [0,255] and then convert the array to `np.uint8`. e.g. `np.uint8(image * 255)` -- or something bit more sophisticated. Binarize the result via `cv2.threshold`, then do `cv2.findContours`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The image is actually a numpy array with the shape `(128, 128)` and elements with real values between `[0.0,1.0]`.

The error from `cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` was due to the fact that you're trying to convert a single channel image from BGR (3 channels) to grayscale (1 channel). Your image is already grayscale, so this step is unnecessary.

The error from [`cv2.findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a) was due to the wrong data type of the elements in the array. The documentation says the following about the input image:

> Source, an 8-bit single-channel image. Non-zero pixels are treated as 1's. Zero pixels remain 0's, so the image is treated as binary . You can use `compare`, `inRange`, `threshold` , `adaptiveThreshold`, `Canny`, and others to create a binary image out of a grayscale or color one. If mode equals to `RETR_CCOMP` or `RETR_FLOODFILL`, the input can also be a 32-bit integer image of labels (`CV_32SC1`).

To fix this, you need to scale the values in your image to range `[0.0,255.0]`, and then cast the result to `np.uint8`:

```
image_8bit = np.uint8(image * 255)
```

---

There are few other issue or quirks about the code in your question.

First of all, in one snippet `cv2.findContours` returns 2 values (OpenCV 2.x), and in the other it returns 3 values (OpenCV 3.x). Which version are you using?

Your first code sample contains the following:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, 1, 2)
```

Avoid using magic numbers. The `1` corresponds to `cv2.RETR_LIST` and the `2` corresponds to `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE`. Since the `RETR_LIST` mode doesn't generate any hierarchy, you can ignored that return value:

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binarized, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Another problem is most likely the fact that originally you didn't explicitly binarize the image (e.g. using `cv2.threshold`). While this won't result in exceptions, the result will probably not make much sense -- `findContours` divides the pixels into two groups -- zeros, and then everything non-zero. You will most likely want them partitioned differently.

```
threshold_level = 127 # Set as you need...
_, binarized = cv2.threshold(image_8bit, threshold_level, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

---

Sample script (OpenCV 3.x):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


# Generate random image matching your description:
# shape is (128,128), values are real numbers in range [0,1]
image = np.random.uniform(0, np.nextafter(1,2), (128,128))

# Scale and convert data type
image_8bit = np.uint8(image * 255)

threshold_level = 127 # Set as you need...
_, binarized = cv2.threshold(image_8bit, threshold_level, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binarized, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# ... processing the contours, etc.
```

Comment: ThNk you very much for your detailed answer! I’ll check this soon. You’re right about your suggestions, I’ll didn’t wanted to get into too much details because I only prototype something using python.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cv2.threshold(image, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,image)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Comment: @BastianSchoettle Make sure the dtype of `image` is `UINT8`.

Comment: This is not very useful, as it doesn't provide any explanation, and doesn't solve the problem of `image` having incorrect data type. The `[1]` is rather useless, since you use the optional "destination" argument and throw the return value away anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The cv2.findContours function accept thresholded images. The error is given because your input image is a grayscale image.

Comment: But I thresholded the image in my second approach?

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the image correctly? Try to output the image you are reading and see what you get.

Comment: Sure, it’s a real valued 2d array which I can plot without any problems using imshow(...).

Comment: This is simply wrong, that error message is due to incorrect data type/channel count. From [the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a): "Non-zero pixels are treated as 1's." You use threshold, since in most cases you want to partition the values differently.